# Aurelia repeat.for two-way binding

Tags: aurelia

I am new to Aurelia Js and am using **repeat.for** for list some text boxes, which may contain some values. Here,listed text-box is fine, problem is am using **value.bind** to bind the previous value/ new value (user input) while typing in text-box, it applying for all model( for all i.companyname)

code :

```js
<div class="row" repeat.for="i of experience_array">
    <input type='text' value.bind='i.companyname'/>
    <input type='text' value.bind='i.experience'/>
</div>
```

Also tried :

```
<div class="row" repeat.for="i of experience_array.length">
    <input type='text' value.bind='$parent.experience_array[i]['companyname']'/>
    <input type='text' value.bind='$parent.experience_array[i]['experience']'/>
</div>
```

How to fix this? Guess, am missing something in aurelia binding concept.

Comment: Can't reproduce this: https://gist.run/?id=196d22b7eef6d461b19924ef6fd4cc07

Comment: Hi @MatthewJamesDavis , here is my exact scenario. Updated the GitRun https://gist.run/?id=a11f8500803a7b6053f980b7aaa48165

Comment: while click the ADD button, am pushing new obj to array. Here the model updating same value. Thanks and do needful.

Comment: would need to look at the JS file to see exactly what you're trying to do., but from what I can see, you shouldn't be binding $parent.experience_array like that

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing an existing object reference (obj) into your list on add, so you are basically adding the same object every time. Therefore, when you edit this object, it will update on all the ui components bound to this object.

When you click add, I'm guessing you want to add a new object. You should create a company class and push a new instance of this class to the list instead of the same obj.

Example: https://gist.run/?id=2237595bdde46cee4658cc14873050d7